# How to get Batch Status from Facebook API using RestFB

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api, restfb

I'm using **RestFB** api to comunicate with Facebook API.

After I send  **batch requests**, I need to  **GET check_batch_request_status** to know the status of all my requests.

Using Postman I did it, but using the **RestFB** API I didn't found how  to do it.

I'm tried to use this, but I think this method is just for the RestFB  "model classes" (HandleResponse.class is my own created class):

`HandleResponse fetchObject = client.fetchObject(HANDLE_ITEMS_BATH_PATH, HandleResponse.class, Parameter.with("handle", handle));`,

With postman:
`https://graph.facebook.com/v8.0/{CATALOG_ID}/check_batch_request_status?handle={HANDLE_ID}`

Is there a way to do it with RestFB API?

Comment: It does not look "false" to me. If you have your own HandleResponse class this should work and is a good solution. I suggest you provide the HandleResponse as PR so everyone can use this in future releases ...

Comment: Hello @Norbert, that code doesn't work. I tried to use my own class, but I think this method is only for API classes

Comment: I think you have to use the `fetchConnection` method, because the returned object seems to be a list of objects and not an object itself. Maybe you should simply open up an issue on Github and we add the needed type then.